# Visualize multiple density plots for multiply imputed data

Tags: r, machine-learning, plot, data-visualization

I have a multiply imputed dataset of class `mids` and I would like to create density plots for each imputed variable. For some reason, I can't get the code to work. I keep getting an error message that says:

`` Error in `[.data.frame`(r, , xvar) : undefined columns selected ``

This is what I have tried:

```
library(mice)
imp <- mice(airquality, seed = 123, 3, print = F)
vars <- c('Ozone', 'Solar.R')
map(1:length(vars), function(x) densityplot(imp, ~vars[[x]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a formula in `densityplot`. Try -

```
library(mice)

imp <- mice(airquality, seed = 123, 3, print = F)
vars <- c('Ozone', 'Solar.R')

list_plots <- purrr::map(seq_along(vars), function(x) 
                 densityplot(imp, as.formula(paste0('~', vars[x]))))
```